# Trimming Specific Text Values in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I am wondering if there is a way to copy the text from one field to a new field, but eliminate specific words.  For example:

```
**Old Field**                         **New Field**

Killbear Provincial Park               Killbear
Quetico Provincial Park                Quetico
La Cloche Provincial Park              La Cloche
Wildcat Hill Provincial Park           Wildcat Hill
```

I thought of trying a trim function, but not all the values have the same start location or trim length.

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your attribute table create a new string column and then use the field calculator as follows:

```
 replace(OLD_FIELD, 'Provincial Park','')
```

The problem with this approach is that your fields won't be trimmed, so you can do the following little hack to address that:

```
 replace(OLD_FIELD, ' Provincial Park ','')
 replace(OLD_FIELD, ' Provincial Park','')
 replace(OLD_FIELD, 'Provincial Park ','')
 replace(OLD_FIELD, 'Provincial Park','')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about removing all the occurrences of " Provincial Park"  A search/replace ought to do the trick.

Comment: Thank you work.  I didn't know you could do a replace in QGIS, I see the Search option, but not the replace

Comment: If you're working with a shapefile, you could edit the .dbf file directly with Excel and do your search/replace there.  Unfortunately newer versions of Excel (2007, 2010) no longer let you save to DBF.  Would work if you have Excel 2003 or earlier.

Comment: There's always LibreOffice Calc which handles DBF files just fine.