# Splitting field with comma as separator into two fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

How to split a "Field" into "Field 1" and "Field 2" when the comma is a separator in the field?

I am using Field Calculator in QGIS.

Comment: Please see the similar question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32996/trimming-specific-text-values-in-qgis-field-calculator since the process to split into new fields will be similar.

Comment: This topic [How to split a text attribute by characters in QGIS 2.6.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127415/how-to-split-a-text-attribute-by-characters-in-qgis-2-6-0) looks similar to me as well.

Comment: And this one as well [How to extract a part of string from fields in QGIS field calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294986/how-to-extract-a-part-of-string-from-fields-in-qgis-field-calculator/294988)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the field calculator, it is quite straightforward.  To get everything to the left of your comma use the following expression:

```
left("myField", strpos("myField", ','))
```

To get everything to the right of the comma use this expression:

```
right("myField", length("myField")-(strpos("myField", ',')+1))
```

Comment: In both cases, comma remains in a new substring. I assume it should include `"-1"`, i.e. `left("myField", strpos("myField", ',')-1)` for `"myField"` values like `'My Street, 1A'`.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:
  `array_to_string(array_slice(string_to_array( "string.Split.By.Dot",'.'),1,3),'.')` => "string.by.dot"
Where 1,3 is index of the start and end of slice.