# How to split text attribute by characters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

Is it possible to make a new column, for example named *"Test"* and store the first part of the column "Name" split by `-`?

See below how it should look like:

[image: example]

Comment: Couldn't you use python's `.split()` function?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes you can.

Use the Field calculator with the following expression:

```
left( "Name", strpos( "Name" ,'-'))
```

The strpos() function will return the index position of the first '-' character and the left() function "trims" the string before that position.

[image]

Comment: That works, but "Name".split('-')[0], per @Branco, might be easier.

Comment: Can you use it in field calculator? Otherwise you need to use the python console to iterate over the features. Compared to that, the field calculator looks more straightforward. There might be better expression using regular expressions.

Comment: You can not use it in filed calculator. So answer provided by Alexandre Neto is more straight forward. But is better to use it with "-1" to avoid adding your charater to output. For example: left( "Name", strpos( "Name" ,':')-1). Otherwise you will end up with "3833-" not just "3833"

Comment: can any one help me to split entire column at a time by '-'. like text to column in excel

Answer (score 14):

You can use the Field calculator with the following expression:

```
string_to_array("Nombre", ' ')
```

[image]

The string_to_array() function splits string into an array using supplied delimiter.

If you want a some position of the array, you can add the position and it will return the value. like this:

```
string_to_array("Nombre", ' ')[2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution by means of PyQGIS.

Let's assume there is a point layer called `"some_points"` with it's attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

layer = iface.activeLayer()
if not layer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")

layer_provider = layer.dataProvider()
layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField("Test", QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()

features=layer.getFeatures()

layer.startEditing()

for f in features:
    attrs = {2: f['info'].split('-')[0]}
    layer_provider.changeAttributeValues({f.id(): attrs})
layer.commitChanges()
```

[image: python_console]

The output will be looking

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [QGIS Python Tutorial: How to Add/Delete Field and Updating Attribute Value](https://www.geodose.com/2018/09/qgis-python-tutorial-add-field-attribute.html)
- [PyQGIS developer cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/pdf/en/QGIS-testing-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf)