# Obtaining specific part of string from field in QGIS attribute table?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, string

I'm having a bit of trouble here with this situation.

[image]

I want "NumeroCamp" only to have the numbers are showing in "Text".

Is there any function in field calculator that could help me with that?

Comment: See this question here:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127415/how-to-split-a-text-attribute-by-characters-in-qgis-2-6-0

Comment: I want to create a new field in my attribute table by returning all digits between the **/** and **_** characters of the field named "location" by aplying the expression given by @ArMoraer to my situation: `regexp_substr( "Text", '/(\\d*)\_' )` However, it does not give the desired result: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92zAd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92zAd.png) How could I adapt the expression to my case?
Many hanks in advance to anyone who can help or give any suggestions.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145591)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145591)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the following expression in the field calculator (tested on QGIS 2.18):

`regexp_substr( "Text", ';(\\d*)\}' )`

This will return all digits (as text) between the `;` and `}` characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
string_to_array("text",';')[1]
```