# Extracting part of string from field in QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, string, function

I want to create a new field in my attribute table. My goal: returning all digits between the / and _ characters of the field named "location" by applying the next expression:

`regexp_substr( "Text", '/(\\d*)\_' )`

based on this working example: [Obtaining specific part of string from field in QGIS attribute table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228213/obtaining-specific-part-of-string-from-field-in-qgis-attribute-table)

However, the expression does not give the desired result in my case:

[image]

Does anyone know any way to modify/accommodate the expression?

Comment: Does it work when you replace the * with a +? I don't really get the syntax either. Alternatively you could run a `substr`, since your path and length of expression is always the same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since the number of characters is the same, you can use the `substr()` function on a new field as in the following expression:

```
substr( "Location" ,17,6)
```

[image]

In the above example, I used `Path` instead of `Location`

Comment: Thx a lot for answering with this example! it works perfectly :) Thxthxthx

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 10):

A couple of issues - first, you don't need to escape (i.e. put a backslash before) the underscore. Your pattern also suggests that the digits follow immediately after a forward slash - which they do not, there is a `w` between them in each of your examples. If this is consistently a `w`, you could do:

```
regexp_substr( "location", '/w(\\d*)_' )
```

but in reality, if you're just trying to get every number before the underscore, you'd be sufficient with:

```
regexp_substr( "location", '(\\d*)_' )
```

As can be seen here:

[image]

Comment: How can i get all the charater after underscore. I tried `regexp_substr( "location", '_(\\d*)' )` but didnt work

Comment: Looks like I found one using `regexp_substr( "location", '(\\d)_' )` Thanks

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome. You can also specify the length of the digits with {5} instead of *

Answer (score 1):

```py
substr("location",16,(length("location")-1))
```

or

```py
substr(substr("location",17,14),1,6)
```

that will return `"W48535"`

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please add some information, why this solution is preferrable over the previously provided ones.