# Expression to extract from infomation

Tags: qgis

[image]

What is the right expression for the QGIS Field calculator to get value string-field like "new field"?

Comment: In python you can slice the string, assuming all your 'field' values are the same length. https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_slice.asp

Comment: You can use the expression suggested in [Extracting part of string from field in QGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/294988/63384). You need to change the range specified in the expression for each part of the string that you need to extract.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new string field `front field` within the `Field calculator`, populating it with the following expression

```
 substr("field",1,4)
```

This way, you extract 4 characters, starting from the first one, of the field `field`. Similarly, you can create and populate `middle field` and `back field` with these other expressions

```
 substr("field",5,5)
 substr("field",10,4)
```

Please note that your example has 5 digits in the first row of the `middle field` but only four in the other two. If that was intentional, you should use a conditional statement similar to

```
case when "field" = '0104030002101' then substr("field",5,5)
else substr("field",5,4) end
```