# Splitting attribute on slash character?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am trying to find a solution to split attributes into two fields at a specific character, slash ("/") in that case.

I tried with [How to split a text attribute by characters in QGIS 2.6.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127415/how-to-split-a-text-attribute-by-characters-in-qgis-2-6-0), but I did not succeeded.

[image]

I want this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

I got this after your function, @Kazuhito

[image]

Comment: Given edits made, I hope reopen vote works. In the meantime, please try `to_int(left("FIELD", strpos( "FIELD" , '[/]')-1))` and `to_int(right("FIELD", length( "FIELD" ) - strpos( "FIELD", '[/]')))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Kazuhito is basically right, you just need to add a condition to correctly fill "Field2". Try this for "Field1":

```
to_int( left( "FIELD", strpos( "FIELD" , '[/]' ) - 1 ) )
```

and this for "Field2":

```
if ( strpos( "FIELD" , '[/]') > 0, 
to_int( right( "FIELD", length( "FIELD" ) - strpos( "FIELD", '[/]' ) ) ), 
NULL)
```

Comment: I am looking to do this exact thing in an ArcGIS Online map.  Any ideas? I am working with a view that has combined info on the same asset, for instance pipe materials.  They are listed in a single attribute, separated by a pipe ( | ).

Comment: Given that you have two new attribute fields, called e.g. `field_1` and `field_2` and your original field called `original`, use the `Field Calculator` and do this for `field_1`: `!original!.split("|")[0]`, and for `field_2`: `!original!.split("|")[1]`. If there is additional whitespace before and after the pipe, include that in the `split()`.

Comment: Except for I am unable to perform a field calculate on a view.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I have no experience with ArcGIS online. But if you cannot calculate attributes there, this task might become difficult anyway. Maybe ask a separate question on that specific topic.