# QGIS label text break in data attribute table

Tags: qgis, labeling, attribute-table

I would like to have my visible label text broken, which is too long.
[image]

I found some solution here:

[How to split text attribute by characters in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127415/how-to-split-text-attribute-by-characters-in-qgis)

but applying the expression to my example:

```
  left( "Text", strpos( "Text" ,'-'))
```

I am getting only B3-, whereas another part of the text is gone.
I need the visible label like this:

```
B3-24F
DP &\PSP2
```

instead of

```
B3-24F DP&\PSP2
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression does exactly what it is supposed to be doing. I guess you mixed up the terms "split" and "wrap".

Go to your label properties and navigate to "formatting". Then fill "wrap on character" with `-`:

[image]

Also check out the other options available there ;)

Answer (score 3):

The labels displayed in your map, and the labels displayed in the text of your question are different.
The labels in the map shows `B3- 24F DP & \PSP2`, and the labels in the text of your question shows `B3-24F DP&\PSP2`. The former text contains more spaces compared with the latter text.

Anyway whatever the case, you need to use `Wrap lines to` and specify the number of characters you want, and then choose `Minimum line length` in the drop-down menu.

In this example, I used 6 characters. Here is the settings, and the final output:

[image]