# Translating OSM 'osmc:symbol' into symbol geometry with QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, symbology

OpenStreetMap uses specific tags to describe route symbols that are used as waymarker (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:osmc:symbol).

For example: `"osmc:symbol"=>"red:white:red_dot"`

I would like to translate that key syntax into a symbol geometry with QGIS similar to the OSM composer does (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Composer).
But the only idea I get into my mind is:

1. build SVG-symbols for every possible combination (with Inkscape)
2. Name every symbol with the relating key (like `'red_white_red_dot.svg'`)
3. Use data defined override at an SVG marker line, where the SVG markers path is set up with the `osmc:symbol` field from the attribute table

That seems to be a not very elegant solution: Too static, too much work and too inflexible.

I'm looking for a better solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in the tagging (osmc:symbol=waycolor:background[:foreground][[:foreground2]:text:textcolor]) can be translated into symbology using the rule-based styling.

Make a layered style and define a rule for every part of the osmc-tag using regex or QGIS-build-in string-expressions.

Or you can 'explode' the tag into different attributes, based on the delimitter ':' (by using eg. virtual fields). An example of splitting based on a ',': [Splitting field with comma as separator into two fields in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63315/splitting-field-with-comma-as-separator-into-two-fields-in-qgis). Then you can assign a symbol based on the values you extracted.

--- EDIT ---

In QGIS 3 this is less complicated with the array-expressions that are provided since.

`array_get(string_to_array('red:white:red_dot',':'),0)` returns `'red'`
 `array_get(string_to_array('red:white:red_dot',':'),1)` returns `'white'`
 `array_get(string_to_array('red:white:red_dot',':'),2)` returns `'red_dot'`

Use `string_to_array()` splitting on `:` to make an array `['red', 'white', 'red_dot']`

Use `array_get()` combined with `0` to get te first part, `1` to get the second part, etc.

Comment: @MAP, thanks to this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318496/7849, there is a more easy way to split the tag into multi parts using virtual fields.  I altered my answer